# Values in rich:dataTable not getting updated in the bean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

This problem is when we are migrating to richfaces4.3 and JSF2.0.

The context is: A rich:dataTable takes answerId, answerDefinition etc in their respective columns. An onchange event is executed on the answerid column, wherein a new row is added.

```
<rich:extendedDataTable rowKeyVar="currentRowVar"
        value="#{DiscQuestMgtController.answerChoiceList}"
            var="dataItem" rowClasses="row1, row2" id="ansChoiceList">
                <rich:column width="160" sortable="false">
                   <h:inputText id="answerID"  value="#{dataItem.answerId}"
                            onchange="addNewRowToAnsChoice('DiscQuestMgtForm',#{fn:length(DiscQuestMgtController.answerChoiceList)});" />     
                </rich:column>
                <rich:column sortable="false">
                    <h:inputText id="choiceValue" value="#{dataItem.choiceValue}"/>
                </rich:column>
                <rich:column sortable="false">
                    <h:inputText id="definitionId"  value="#{dataItem.definition}"/>
                </rich:column>
    </rich:extendedDataTable>
```

When retrieving the values into the dataTable, the working is fine. But when I enter the value into answerId(the first cell) and shift focus, the existing row is totally eliminated creating a new row.

**addNewRowToAnsChoice** , JS method, does few validations of the entered values  and in turn calls a a4j function .. **addEmptyAnsChoice** .. The below is the code, that adds a new row, in the backing bean.

//AddNewRow

```
public void addEmptyRow( ActionEvent ae )
    {

        removeEmptyChoiceRow();
        String logStr = " DiscQuestMgtController:addEmptyRow()>>>";
        logger.debug( logStr + " Entered" );
        AnswerChoiceBean bean = new AnswerChoiceBean();
        bean.setQuestionId( discQuestBean.getQuestionId() );
        logger.debug( logStr + "Choice list size: answerChoiceList size-->",answerChoiceList.size() ); //@abc
        if ( answerChoiceList.size() == 1 )
            answerChoiceList.get( 0 ).setQuestionId( discQuestBean.getQuestionId() );
        if ( !answerChoiceList.contains( bean ) )
            answerChoiceList.add( bean );
        logger.debug( logStr + " Returned" );
    }
```

removeEmptyChoiceRow() checks if there are any existing empty rows and deletes them, to add a new row. @abc, the list size is always the default one. (there is always one row on page load), which is just not changing though the values are entered. Pls suggest!!

This is the a4j:function:

```
<a4j:jsFunction name="addEmptyAnsChoice"
                render="ansChoiceList,addDiscQuest,applyDiscQuest"
                actionListener="#{DiscQuestMgtController.addEmptyRow}"
                oncomplete="focusToNewCell('DiscQuestMgtForm',#{fn:length(DiscQuestMgtController.answerChoiceList)});">
            </a4j:jsFunction>
```

Comment: can you include method definition for `#{DiscQuestMgtController.answerChoiceList}` as well and scopes of associated beans?

Comment: The mentioned input-field triggers the function `addNewRowToAnsChoice` onchange. This is one of your functions. To really help you over here, please remove parts of the xhtml not being important (like f:facet name="header", styles, e.g.), which makes understanding your problem easier. Also provide the connected JavaScript functions and managed beans like e.g. `DiscQuestMgtController`.

Comment: @mzzzzb the bean is session-scoped. Pls see my edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A major change from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2 is the introduction of the attributes `render` and `execute` replacing `rerender`.

- `execute` partly updates the model of the marked part of the tree
- `render` renders the marked part of the tree and sends it via AJAX for replacing the original part.

This is handy, when e.g. a Listener updates values also being shown as input-fields on the page.

**Update:** You are calling `addNewRowToAnsChoice` on change of `answerId`, calling the `a4j:jsFunction` `addEmptyAnsChoice` later on.

There the elements `ansChoiceList` ,`addDiscQuest`,`applyDiscQuest` get rerendered, but nothing is being sent for `execute`. So the line you entered the `answerId` in - well - is never updated on server side.

In the next step, in the actionListener you remove all empty lines (so also this one, too) and add a fresh line on the bottom.

IMO, try skipping the jsFunction call and instead letting the same stuff being executed as a `f:ajax` or `a4j:ajax`. The (untested) code might look like following...

```
<h:inputText id="answerID"  value="#{dataItem.answerId}"
                        onchange="<yourValidationFunction>">
    <a4j:ajax execute="@this"
            render="ansChoiceList addDiscQuest applyDiscQuest"
            actionListener="#{DiscQuestMgtController.addEmptyRow}"
            oncomplete="focusToNewCell('DiscQuestMgtForm',#{fn:length(DiscQuestMgtController.answerChoiceList)});">
    </a4j:ajax>
</h:inputText>
```

This way you keep the ID from the value to be updated on server side.

Hope it works and helps...

Comment: Thanks a TONNN.. It did work.. I added execute attribute..  :) @L-Ray

Comment: Cool ... 'nd thnx for the feedback.